# Grouping MySQL column (Product Name) with Highest Value and Lowest value each Month

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, min

I have a Table with the following:

`Table Name : Prices`

`Columns: IdPrices, products_ID, supplier_ID, Price, PriceDate`

I need a query result with the following

Find the Lowest price of an item on each month
Find the Highest price of an item on each month

Kindly refer the image below!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PriceDate),0) [Month], MAX(Price) HighPrice, MIN(Price) LowPrice
FROM Prices
GROUP BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PriceDate),0)
```

Comment: Now I am getting the values by using the below query...

SELECT
  MONTH(prices.PriceDate) AS Month,
  products.ProductName,
  MIN(prices.Price) AS min_price,
  MAX(prices.Price) AS max_price,
  prices.fkProductID
FROM products
  INNER JOIN prices
    ON products.idProducts = prices.fkProductID
WHERE prices.fkProductID = 8
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY min_price DESC